# Regular expression in Ingress 1.8.1 is not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I followed the official document to install the NGINX ingress and tried to test with the Kubenretes /foo/bar/ example for regular expression.

Example:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-3
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/bar/bar
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /foo/bar/[A-Z0-9]{3}
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

NGINX config file expected content:

```
location ~* "^/foo/bar/[A-Z0-9]{3}" {
  ...
}

location ~* "^/foo/bar/bar" {
  ...
}
```

Actual content

```
location /foo/bar/[A-Z0-9]{3} {
  ...
}

location /foo/bar/bar {
  ...
}
```

Issue:
I am not able to get the same NGINX file content in ingress-controller.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Paste your actual result as well.

Comment: I have deployed your ingress file in my cluster where I use ingress 1.19.3 and I'm having your desired config. Are you able to update nginx ingress and check if it helps?